# Magento 2: Apache mod version not enabled/installed/allowed by host, causes 500 error on all pages due to failing .htaccess files

Tags: magento2.2, installation, htaccess, http-error-500, http-error-404

I created a fresh install of Magento 2.2.2 on a debian server using php7.1 and mysql 5.7.

Once files were extracted, I was unable to access the setup wizard and received 500 errors from all pages.

In order to troubleshoot the problem, I deleted the `.htaccess` files in order to access the setup page and install Magento. At this point, with an incorrect Apache configuration due to missing `.htaccess` configuration, the homepage appears as plain HTML, with CSS styles omitted. The admin login page returns a 404 error.

I replaced the `.htaccess` file by changing to the Magento working directory and issuing the command:

```
cp .htaccess.sample .htaccess
```

The apache error log read:

`Invalid command 'php_value'`

I commented out all lines of the .htaccess files containing `php_value` and a new error was displayed:

`Invalid command '<IfVersion'`

Comment: @sv3n Why do you just make pointless edits? You do realise that stackexchange rep isn't actual currency?

Comment: I do not get any REP for edits since 2k REP. Just edited a tag and rolled back for some reasons. Nothing to worry about ;)

Comment: Ok no worries. Apologies. Did read up on this in meta after commenting.

Comment: Hi after all this editing I am unable to sign in Admin

Comment: @ShobanPoshala You made the edits that I explain in this question? That is not a solution. I was explaining that this is how I began troubleshooting and confirmed that `mod_version` is not enabled. If you are having issues with `mod_version` then please undo all the changes you made based on this question and follow the instructions in my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem is caused when apache's `mod_version` module is not enabled. Unfortunately, my host does not allow me to enable this module and so I have devised the following workaround:

#### Step 1

Open `[magento_root]/.htaccess` with your favourite text editor.

You will notice, towards the end of the file, there are numerous entries following this format:

```
<Files composer.json>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
<Files composer.lock>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
...
```

#### Step 2

The exact procedure here is dependent on the version of apache that your server is running. Mine runs 2.4, so I have removed all `<IfVersion />` statements and replaced them with the content of their relevant clause, like so:

```
<Files composer.json>
    Require all denied
</Files>
<Files composer.lock>
    Require all denied
</Files>
...
```

This process must be repeated until there are no instances of `<IfVersion />` remaining in the document.

#### Step 3

Open `[magento_root]/pub/.htaccess` with your favourite text editor and repeat the process laid out in step 2.

**Note:** In the event that this process has been carried out and then the apache version is changed (i.e. the server was running apache 2.2 and upgraded to 2.4), then files must be restored by replacing both edited files with the relevant `.htaccess.sample`, and following the above process from the beginning.

As mentioned in [Erica Southworth's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/225959/60221), the list I provide is not exhaustive, but it is all that is needed in order to recover basic functionality. Here is the list of all files containing `IfVersion` queries, for continuity:

```
app/.htaccess 
bin/.htaccess 
generated/.htaccess 
lib/.htaccess 
phpserver/.htaccess 
pub/.htaccess 
var/.htaccess 
vendor/.htaccess  
setup/config/.htaccess 
setup/performance-toolkit/.htaccess 
setup/src/.htaccess 
setup/view/.htaccess  
vendor/magento/magento2-base/.htaccess  
pub/media/customer/.htaccess 
pub/media/downloadable/.htaccess 
pub/media/import/.htaccess 
pub/media/theme_customization/.htaccess  
vendor/magento/magento2-base/vendor/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/var/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/pub/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/phpserver/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/generated/.htaccess  
vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/bin/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/app/.htaccess  
vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/config/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/performance-toolkit/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/src/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/view/.htaccess  
vendor/magento/magento2-base/pub/media/customer/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/pub/media/downloadable/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/pub/media/import/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/pub/media/theme_customization/.htaccess
```

Comment: `<IfVersion < 2.4> order allow,deny deny from all </IfVersion> <IfVersion >= 2.4> Require all denied </IfVersion>` how to change this one, it does not contain <Files composer.lock> Tag

Comment: @IzharMehdi hi sorry for the delay. Just remove all the `<>` tags and leave the statement in place which applies to your version, without any surrounding tags at all.

Answer (score 4):

Note you will need to remove the "IfVersion" commands from every .htaccess file in Magento, after the installation too. These are the files I had to modify with a fresh install Magento2 (2.4) and on the godaddy linux platform.

```
app/.htaccess 
bin/.htaccess 
generated/.htaccess 
lib/.htaccess 
phpserver/.htaccess 
pub/.htaccess 
var/.htaccess 
vendor/.htaccess  
setup/config/.htaccess 
setup/performance-toolkit/.htaccess 
setup/src/.htaccess 
setup/view/.htaccess  
vendor/magento/magento2-base/.htaccess  
pub/media/customer/.htaccess 
pub/media/downloadable/.htaccess 
pub/media/import/.htaccess 
pub/media/theme_customization/.htaccess  
vendor/magento/magento2-base/vendor/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/var/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/pub/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/phpserver/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/generated/.htaccess  
vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/bin/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/app/.htaccess  
vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/config/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/performance-toolkit/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/src/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/view/.htaccess  
vendor/magento/magento2-base/pub/media/customer/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/pub/media/downloadable/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/pub/media/import/.htaccess 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/pub/media/theme_customization/.htaccess
```

Comment: Thanks Erica! I have added this list to my solution, for clarity. Could I ask, out of curiosity, which host/package are you using please?

Answer (score 1):

"mod_version" is disabled by default in Wamp so it should be on to avoid 500 internal server error.

To make it enable, kindly follow below steps

check you "httpd.conf" which is generally located in /wamp/bin/apache/apache(XXX)/conf/httpd.conf

Search by "mod_version" and uncomment this line "#LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so"

Don't forget to restart all services of wamp.