# Uncaught Exception: Warning: SessionHandler::open(): Cannot call session save handler in a recursive manner

Tags: magento2, admin, session, logout

I move my magento project from localhost to shared server. Now since mod_version was not installed and the hosting provider said that enabling the module was not covered of the plan. So I followed the link below as a work around to make it run.

[Magento 2: Apache mod version not enabled/installed/allowed by host, causes 500 error on all pages due to failing .htaccess files](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206039/magento-2-apache-mod-version-not-enabled-installed-allowed-by-host-causes-500)

After all the hard work, the magento now was running but I got the following error whenever I try to log out in admin side

```
[30-Aug-2018 01:09:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  Uncaught Exception: Warning: SessionHandler::open(): Cannot call session save handler in a recursive manner in /vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php on line 72 in vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'SessionHandler:...', '/home/username...', 72, Array)
#1 /vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php(72): SessionHandler->open('host_here...', 'admin')
#2 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler->open('host_here...', 'admin')
#3 /vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(189): session_start()
#4 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/Message/Session/Interceptor.php(50): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->start()
#5 /vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionM in /vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php on line 61
[30-Aug-2018 01:09:57 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path:host_here:port_here) in /vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php on line 189
```

Before I am using files to store session but I experiencing random/immediate logout whenever I do basic operations (add items, edit, etc.). Followed everything I find on google but no luck. Now I switched to memcached and it solved the issue. (I already experiencing the log out issue here.)

So now i using memcached to store session files. I assume that logout issue will be solve but when I tried to log out its still not redirecting and stuck in http://sub.domain.com/admin/admin/auth/logout/key/unique_key_here/ and error_log shows above error.

Didn't experience this on localhost. Im using v2.2.4. Please help anyone!