# Magento 2 - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, backend, http-error-500

sorry for creating another 500 Internal server error thread but I couldn't find any solution for my problem yet.

We have a managed server from German provider 1&1 and we have a running magento website on it with 1.9.4.1 which works fine.

I installed a fresh Magento 2.3.1 on this server and installation completes without any problems, all requirements like `php7.2, Apache 2.4`, requested extensions and file permissions are fine.

After the installation the backend gives 500 Internal Server error and frontend is without any design. I figured out that for the frontend the rewrites for pub/static are not working and found a changed .htaccess for pub/static to get the design loading on the frontend.
But still any links in the frontend and the whole backend end with 500...

I tried solutions found on the web like deleting .htaccess, file permissions and disabling static rewrites in mySQL but they didn't help. I can not reach developer mode in ssh so I enabled developer mode with env.php, debug shows errors like:

> [2019-05-21 09:42:27] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: 
>   {"method":"GET","url":"http://test.tudi-billo.de/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"interception"}}
>   []
>
> [2019-05-21 09:42:36] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: 
>   {"method":"GET","url":"http://test.tudi-billo.de/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"SYSTEM_CONFIG"}}
>   []
>
> [2019-05-21 09:42:37] main.INFO: Broken reference: the
>   'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to
>   'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>
> [2019-05-21 09:42:37] main.INFO: Broken reference: the
>   'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to
>   'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []

Now I'm stuck and the server provider won't help anymore as they say Magento is the problem, not their server. I guess there is an overall problem with rewrites and therefore the backend can not be found.

Any idea how to find the error or how to solve this?

Comment: Have you disabled https on front end and backend as well? check permission as well

Comment: Have you checked your error logs on the server? This sounds like an apache_mod issue.

Comment: Have you checked if Apache Rewrites is enabled in your browser?

Comment: https is disabled for both, front and backend, permissions I tried as I found here in the forum and also with 777 for all, no difference.

Comment: I guess it is a rewrite problem, how to check Apache rewrites in browser?

Comment: Sorry in server, check your apache configuration for these lines <Directory /var/www/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 AllowOverride <value from Apache site>
 Order allow,deny
 Require all granted
</Directory>

Answer (score 0):

Go to bootstrap.php it will be inside app (use this to edit sudo nano app/bootstrap.php) and then uncomment this line ini_set('display_errors', 1); so that you can debug your error

Comment: let me know if any issues

Comment: I made this change but where do I see the errors? debug.log still shows the same and when opening backend no error shows except of 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: in developer mode the files are automatically generated when requested and not found. So this should not be a Problem.

When facing a 500 error the first thing you should do is search for your webserver error log.

When running on apache it can mostly be found in one of these 2 locations:

Comment: /var/log/httpd/ -> centos, archlinux ...

/var/log/apache2/ -> debian, ubuntu ..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on one install - turned out to be `mod_version` apache module is not enabled.  This needs enabling.  Or you need to edit .htacesss and take out those parts.  Without it the site will 500.  In this case this is a hosting issue.

[Magento 2: Apache mod version not enabled/installed/allowed by host, causes 500 error on all pages due to failing .htaccess files](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206039/magento-2-apache-mod-version-not-enabled-installed-allowed-by-host-causes-500)

I also recommend using a check script to make sure you have everything you need.  You should as Magento installed.  But worth a check.

Here is one such script

https://github.com/sjanjic/magento2-check/blob/master/index.php

check.php

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

function result($value, $result)
{
    if ($result) {
        return array('css' => 'success', 'note' => $value . ': OK');
    }
    return array('css' => 'danger', 'note' => $value . ': FAIL');
}

function apacheModules()
{
    $results = array();
    preg_match('/([\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+)/', apache_get_version(), $version);
    $results[0] = array('css' => 'danger', 'note' => 'Version: ' . $version[0]);
    if (version_compare($version[0], '2.2') >= 0) {
        $results[0] = array('css' => 'success', 'note' => 'Version: ' . $version[0]);
    }
    $requiredModules = array('mod_rewrite','mod_expires');
    $apacheModules = apache_get_modules();
    foreach ($requiredModules as $req) {
        $results[] = result($req, in_array($req, $apacheModules));
    }
    return $results;
}

function phpExtensions()
{
    $results = array();
    preg_match('/([\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+)/', phpversion(), $version);
    $ver = $version[0];
    $results[0] = array('css' => 'danger', 'note' => 'Version: ' . $ver);
    if ((version_compare($ver, '5.6.5', '>=') && version_compare($ver, '7.0.0', '<')) || version_compare($ver, '7.0.2',
            '==') || version_compare($ver, '7.0.4', '==') || version_compare($ver, '7.0.6', '>=')
    ) {
        $results[0] = array('css' => 'success', 'note' => 'Version: ' . $ver);
    }
    $requiredExtensions = array(
        'curl',
        'gd',
        'intl',
        'mbstring',
        'mcrypt',
        'openssl',
        'PDO',
        'SimpleXML',
        'soap',
        'xml',
        'xsl',
        'zip',
        'json',
        'iconv',
        'Zend OPcache',
        'xdebug',
    );
    $phpExtensions = get_loaded_extensions();
    foreach ($requiredExtensions as $req) {
        $results[] = result($req, in_array($req, $phpExtensions));
    }
    return $results;
}

function phpOptionalExtensions()
{
    $optionalExtensions = array(
        'imagick',
    );
    $phpExtensions = get_loaded_extensions();
    $results = array();
    foreach ($optionalExtensions as $opt) {
        $results[] = result($opt, in_array($opt, $phpExtensions));
    }
    return $results;
}
//apacheModules();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Magento 2 requirements check script</h1>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Apache</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php foreach (apacheModules() as $result): ?>
                <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $result['css'] ?>" role="alert"><?php echo $result['note'] ?></div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">PHP</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div role="alert" class="alert alert-warning">Loaded php.ini file: <?php echo php_ini_loaded_file()?></div>
            <?php foreach (phpExtensions() as $result): ?>
                <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $result['css'] ?>" role="alert"><?php echo $result['note'] ?></div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Optional PHP Extension</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php foreach (phpOptionalExtensions() as $result): ?>
                <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $result['css'] ?>" role="alert"><?php echo $result['note'] ?></div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```